# Java EE persistent scheduled task?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1, java-ee-7

I'm a bit stuck and maybe you others have some good advice on how to go on. We are developing a standard Java EE/Wildfly 10.01 app and would like to create tasks that are persistent and should be executed only once at a certain date. I found a lot examples on how to execute stuff periodically and that JBeret can be used to define reusable Tasks/Jobs but I fail to find any example or document describing a solution for our certain use case. 
As a side note: we would like to use standard stuff and avoid to use complex additional frameworks/services like Quartz.

I hope someone here can help us out. Thanks in advance, Gerrit.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html not sure if it's enough

Comment: You can use JEE's TimerService and the @Schedule annotation with specified date when to fire a task.

Comment: @slwk that would execute the tasks periodically

Comment: not really if you give specific date, since it supports year

Comment: @mklimasz indeed. 
You can use: `@Schedule(dayOfMonth="3", month="2", year="2017", hour="11", minute="10", second="0")`

Comment: Thnx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Java EE has a @Scheduled annotation.

There is a deep tutorial for it: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

This is by default persistent, but it can be turned off. That's it, nothing else needed :)